# Rails 3 Devise adding field to registartion form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to add new field to registration form.
For this:
1. I created field named **user_name** in my database
2. I changed my model

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_name
```

3. I changed the view

```
<%= f.label :user_name %>
<%= f.text_field :user_name %>
```

But I got the error: **undefined method 'user_name' for #User:0x1ff0e30**

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Got to irb and type name of class used by devise (I suppose User or AdminUser). Show us the output.

Comment: I got the result: => User(id: integer, address: string, email: string, encrypted_password: string,
 confirmation_token: string, confirmed_at: datetime, confirmation_sent_at: datet
ime, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_cr
eated_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_s
ign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, failed
_attempts: integer, unlock_token: string, locked_at: datetime, created_at: datet
ime, updated_at: datetime, authentication_token: string, **user_name: string**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you create the field? It looks like the model isn't recognizing that the field is there which could be one of two things.

First, you've not run the migration to add the field to the table in the database. This is the most common mistake of people when this error is encountered.

Second, you *did* add the field, but you added it to the wrong database. Less common, but still a potential possibility.

Comment: First, I did **rails g migration add_user_name_to_user user_name:string**. Second, I launched **rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120229121145**

Comment: Just `rake db:migrate` would be enough.

Comment: I found the solution: simple restart web server )
Thanks to everyone for help!